# Unable to retrieve all tr elements of a web table using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-testing

[image]

As seen in the picture, I have more than 1 table rows. However, I am unable to retrieve any of those table rows except for the first row.

Code:

```
roster_tbody = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody")
tr = roster_tbody.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
print("number of table rows: " + str(len(tr)))
for trEl in tr:
    print(trEl.text)
```

Expected output: 
 I should be seeing all dates, days, year and 'Full'(if applicable) being printed for each row.

Actual output:

[image]

What I've tried:

1)

```
tr = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "tr"))
)
```

It does not work as well and return the first table row only.

2)

```
row_2 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody/tr[2]")
print(row_2.text)
```

Outcome:

[image]

3)
changing `//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody` to `.//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody` does not work as well

4. Searching for tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGsrw.png) from elements panel: tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGsrw.png) was found and highlighted.

[image]

5. Searching for tr from console panel: all 37 tr was found.

[image]

6)

```
roster_tbody = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody/tr")
j = 1
for i in range(len(tr)):
    element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody/tr)[{j}]")
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    print(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    j = j + 1
```

Output:
[image]

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: code looks okay with respect to static HTML, to debug/recreate need URL or full page HTML(although not sure if full-page HTML will help with debug)

Comment: What does a browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr") return? Code looks good, maybe there are 2 tbody elements?

Comment: @TacoVerhagen browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr") returns the same output as the screenshot. I just did another check and there is only 1 tbody element in the entire web page. It is so weird that it only retrieves the first row successfully and nothing else.

Comment: @simpleApp I can't provide the full page as it is a URL from my work organization that requires login credentials. I was wondering if I could automate booking my working slots using python

Comment: sure, we understand. Try this to debug, follow [through this](https://yizeng.me/2014/03/23/evaluate-and-validate-xpath-css-selectors-in-chrome-developer-tools/)  and see if you type `//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody/tr[2]"` does it highlight row 2 with green ? if you see this then python/selenium needs to be tweaked.

Comment: Can you share the link to the website, and point out the table you're trying to extract data from?

Comment: @ShineJ Hi, sorry but I can't share the link to the website. it is my work organization's website which requires me to login. I was just wondering if I could automate booking my working slots using python and it led to this problem

Comment: @simpleApp Hi, yes the rows are highlighted in green as updated in the screenshots above. What did you mean when you said python/selenium needs to be tweaked?

Comment: tweak I mean, we need to fix code in python. it's hard to suggest something here further. few more options : The checkbox(B-WDL) you have on the webpage, I hope you have code in selenium to click those first before checking the rows data; devtools results you have posted are from browser instance launched by selenium?

Comment: @simpleApp I did not have any code to click on those checkboxes as my thought process was that if I could not iterate any rows of data, I would not even be able to click on those boxes by accessing for example, tr[3] or tr[10] etc. However, I did add a code to test out clicking that specific check box using the xpath. The result was: unable to locate element of that specific xpath, similar to screenshot 2.

Comment: yes, you are right! if can't get the element cant click. sorry, I ran out of the options to debug this further.

Comment: @simpleApp Also, the devtools results I posted were from browser instance launched by selenium. However, it was verified with the normal browser.

Comment: @simpleApp no worries, really appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

Since there are lot of tr tags, I would assume scrolling to each element would be neccessary.

Also, I am using indexing to look for each web element.

**Code :**

```
roster_tbody = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody/tr")
j = 1
for i in range(len(roster_tbody)):
    element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, f"(//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody/tr)[{j}]")
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    print(element.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    j = j + 1
```

Comment: the results of your code is shown in image 6. likewise, only the first row was return

Comment: Is URL public ? Also, print this `print(len(roster_tbody))` before going inside the loop and let me know the output.

Comment: url is public however it requires login credentials. Output of len is 1. as seen in screenshot 1, there is only 1 tbody in the web page

Comment: Well I am printing `//*[@id='tableDay']/tbody/tr`, it can not be 1

Comment: I know it can't be 1 as well. However, as seen the first code section, ```print("number of table rows: " + str(len(tr)))``` prints out 'number of table rows: 1', in screenshot 2